# Can "apocryphal" be used to mean "not true"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I always thought that *apocryphal* should just mean "of doubtful authenticity". But more and more I am noticing that people use it positively to mean *mythical* or *untrue*, especially in phrases such as "This is probably apocryphal, but...".

The use of *probably* here is what seems to indicate a difference in understanding of the term. If something is doubtful, then it is just doubtful, not "probably doubtful".

Comment: You're right on both counts. *Apocryphal* originally meant only *of doubtful authorship*, but over time, it's meaning has been extended to *fictitious*, which by now is so well established its [even recorded in dictionaries](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=apocryphal). So the construction "*probably apocryphal*" simply means "*I'm betting this is just a made-up story, but I heard...*".

Comment: Can a diamond mod switch the *it's* and *its* in my previous comment? That's just plain embarrassing.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: *apocryphal* is routinely used to mean *not [convincingly] true*.

Although the concepts are intertwined, the definition of *[apocryphal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apocryphal)* denotes **authenticity** not authorship:

> adjective
>
> 1 (Of a story or statement) of doubtful authenticity, although widely
>   circulated as being true:
>   *ODO*

The connotation of **authorship** is rooted in the ongoing theological dispute about the biblical *[Apocrypha](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Apocrypha&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> late 14c., neuter plural of Late Latin apocryphus "secret, not
>   approved for public reading,"
>
> from Greek apokryphos "hidden;
>   obscure," thus "(books) of unknown authorship" (especially those
>   included in the Septuagint and Vulgate but not originally written in
>   Hebrew and not counted as genuine by the Jews),
>
> from apo- "away"
>   (see apo-) + kryptein "to hide" (see crypt).
>   *etymonline.com*

Some early Jewish and Christian leaders demanded that the followers of their sects avoid the *[Apocrypha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrypha)*, because they were **deemed less trustworthy** than their *[canon of scripture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon)*. Faithfulness to the sect's unique truth claims was the primary concern, but authorship was posited as the most important **measure of veracity**.

In the extended use of *apocryphal*, authorship does not always rise to the same level for determining authenticity, but a doubtful source always casts some doubt on the reliability of any truth claim.

Answer (score -1):

**Apocryphal** can rightly be used to cast doubts on the credibility and authenticity of a subject in question, such usages are to challenge the reliability.